# Rx: Count of Grouped Events in Moving Window

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net, eventstoredb

I have started looking at using Reactive Extensions with EventStore. As a proof of concept, I'd like to see if I can get Rx to consume an event stream and output the count of events grouped by type for a window of one second.

So, say that I am consuming a stream with the name "orders", I'd like to see something like the following appear in the console:

```
OrderCreated 201
OrderUpdated 111
```

(a second passes..)

```
OrderCreated 123
OrderUpdated 132
```

And so on.

So far, I have been able to get an output of the count of **all** events per second. But can't seem to be able to group them by event type.

The code I am using is based on a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jen20/5082745) by James Nugent:

```
internal class EventStoreRxSubscription
{
    public Subject<ResolvedEvent> ResolvedEvents { get; }

    public Subject<SubscriptionDropReason>  DroppedReasons { get; }
    public EventStoreSubscription Subscription { get; }

    public EventStoreRxSubscription(EventStoreSubscription subscription, Subject<ResolvedEvent> resolvedEvent, Subject<SubscriptionDropReason> droppedReasons)
    {
        Subscription = subscription;
        ResolvedEvents = resolvedEvent;
        DroppedReasons = droppedReasons;
    }
}

static class EventStoreConnectionExtensions
{
    public static Task<EventStoreRxSubscription> SubscribeTo(this IEventStoreConnection connection, string streamName, bool resolveLinkTos)
    {
        return Task<EventStoreRxSubscription>.Factory.StartNew(() => {

            var resolvedEvents = new Subject<ResolvedEvent>();
            var droppedReasons = new Subject<SubscriptionDropReason>();

            var subscriptionTask = connection.SubscribeToStreamAsync(streamName, resolveLinkTos, 
                                                                    (subscription, @event) => resolvedEvents.OnNext(@event), 
                                                                    (subscription, dropReason, arg3) => droppedReasons.OnNext(dropReason));
            subscriptionTask.Wait();

            return new EventStoreRxSubscription(subscriptionTask.Result, resolvedEvents, droppedReasons);
        });
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         var connection = EventStoreConnection.Create(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1113));
         connection.ConnectAsync();

         var subscriptionTask = connection.SubscribeTo("orders", true);
         subscriptionTask.Wait();

         var events = subscriptionTask.Result.ResolvedEvents;

         var query = events.Timestamp()
                .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                .Select(e => e.Count);

         query.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

         Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
```

Comment: did my updated answer help you out with this?

Comment: Yes. I just got a chance to try it out and it looks good. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done something similar to this before, I used `Throttle` to group all events within a set frequency, however you could use `Buffer` to get the count/collection for every period.

The example below provides an abstract example of how I achieved this, where `AggregateType` and `AggregateFunction` would be replaced by your own type and aggregation.

`GroupByUntil` allows you to group by a type within a set period.

```
subscription = observable
    .GroupByUntil(e => e.Key, e => e.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
    .SelectMany(e => e.Aggregate(new AggregateType(), (a, e) => AggregateFunction(a, e))
    .Subscribe(onNext, onError, onCompleted);
```

**EDIT**

Below is a quick example I've knocked up to show how it can be done

```
public class EventType
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class AggregatedType
{
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public delegate void ExampleEventHandler(EventType e);

    public static event ExampleEventHandler Event;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var subscription = Observable.FromEvent<ExampleEventHandler, EventType>(e => Event += e, e => Event -= e)
            .GroupByUntil(e => e.Type, e => e.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
            .SelectMany(e => e
                .Select(ev => new AggregatedType {  EventType = ev.Type })
                .Aggregate(new AggregatedType(), (a, ev) => new AggregatedType { EventType = ev.EventType, Count = a.Count + 1 }))
            .Subscribe(OnAggregaredEvent, OnException, OnCompleted);

        Event(new EventType { Type = "A" });
        Event(new EventType { Type = "A" });
        Event(new EventType { Type = "B" });
        Event(new EventType { Type = "B" });

        SpinWait.SpinUntil(()=> false, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        Event(new EventType { Type = "A" });
        Event(new EventType { Type = "A" });
        Event(new EventType { Type = "B" });
        Event(new EventType { Type = "B" });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void OnAggregaredEvent(AggregatedType aggregated)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}, Count: {1}", aggregated.EventType, aggregated.Count);
    }

    static void OnException(Exception ex)
    {
    }

    static void OnCompleted()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried turning your abstract example into code but am really struggling to get something workable. AggregateFunction seems to take in each member of the sequence, whereas I'd like to get a count of all members for each event type.